# How to add my framework on gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

I did a lot of research and I could't get one thing I have created my own framework and I want put in on gradle.

I do not want copy paste every time a lot of code from one project to another.

I want to do like this

```
compile 'xxxxx'
```

What should I do here to set this up?

Comment: What do you mean your framework? Could you possibly mean your library? Have you packaged your library in a jar file ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve it you have some ways:

1. **publish your library (artifact) in central maven or jcenter.**
   These repo are public, it means that your artifacts will be public.
2. use a **github repo** and the [**jitpack** plugin](https://jitpack.io/)
   These repo are public, it means that your artifacts will be public.
3. publish the aar in a **local maven repo** (local o private)
   In this case the artifact can be private.

**To publish** a library in Central Maven or JCenter, it is very long to explain in an answer. Hovewer you can read these posts:

- Publish on [JCenter](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en)
- Publish on [Central Maven](http://gmariotti.blogspot.it/2013/09/publish-aar-file-to-maven-central-with.html)

To install a **private maven** , you can evaluate the nexus repository.
Check this [link](https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Gabriele You gave me the way how to do this.

Comment: bro, you need to make that a FAQ -- same answer over and over :)   can you expand with more specifics?  Or maybe, short and sweet is good...?